# Apple Transporter failing to upload IPA with error: Failed to create .itmsp for 'appname' status code 401

Tags: ios, testflight, ipa

I am trying to upload an ipa to Transporter (to get new version on TestFlight) and have successfully done it in the past. However, today I tried to upload and it stopped with this error popup on the screen:

Failed to create the .itmsp for 'Appname'.
The web service returned an unexpected status code (401 instead of 200)

screenshot: [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKML2.png)

Notes:

- tried multiple times today with same issue
- App is a Xamarin app thus can't upload the other way (Xcode > Archive)
- using Transporter app released by Apple

Comment: Try waiting 24 hours?

Comment: @matt just tried again (so 24 hours later) and no luck

Answer (score 15):

Try completely shutting down your device and then turning it back on and trying.

I had the same issue for most of yesterday and couldn't find a solution, and just now a reboot of my MacBook made it work instantly.

Comment: Worked for me. It makes me sad that this is (sometimes) the solution.

Comment: Simply restarting Transporter was enough in my case

Answer (score 8):

Just relaunch Transporter app, or quit and r-enter it again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by matching the case of the SKU. `com.company.appName` wasn't accepted. I had to change it to `com.Company.AppName` on my `info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

Some times it may due to memory issue. Check your memory. Free space up to minimum 2 GB for big project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create an entry for your app in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Shut Down Your Device And everything Ok

Answer (score 0):

I am getting that issue when I left build number empty. It seems like you could face the same sort of issues if you left Identity into under General tab.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was memory full issue. Freed up some space and the .ipa file was immediately accepted!